# Android buttons/app not working

Tags: android, xml, button

I must be doing something very stupid. This is my second app - the first worked fine (honest).

I've just got a basic title screen with a button on it but nothing happens when I click on the button. The screen appears correctly but no response from the button - I've tried it in debug but nothing...no error, no info message, zilch (I'm using the AVD).

This is my code...

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.spyeye"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/spyEyeTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.spyeye.TitleScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.spyeye.createNewGameActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.spyeye.TitleScreen" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.spyeye.TitleScreen" />
    </activity>
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".TitleScreen" >

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/spyeyelogo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/logo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:onClick="newGame"
    android:text="@string/newTxt" />
```

Java file:

```
public class TitleScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title_screen);
}

public void newGame (View v) {
    // create intent to start another activity
    Intent newGameIntent = new Intent(this, createNewGameActivity.class);

    startActivity(newGameIntent);
}
}
```

The only major difference between this and my other app is that I have now tried to use a single style file and I've re-designed my own buttons:

```
 <style name="spyEyeTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/myButton</item>

</style>

<style name="myButton" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    <item name="android:background">#008080</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10sp</item>

</style>
```

Anyone see the obvious mistake I must have made?

Comment: I don't see any onClickListeners for the button or anything to handle the click.

Comment: Where is the code for your createNewGameActivity.class?

Comment: Derp. Didn't see that.

Comment: For grins remove the imageview and see if the button clicks.

Comment: @mtorres - I have that code but didn't want to confuse things - the onClick doesn't seem to be working so it is not getting there anyway...

Comment: @snowCrabs - nope, no good...

Comment: how do you know it is actually getting to the newGame method? Do you have a Log on it?

Comment: I added a log and it is not getting to newGame, although it does get into onCreate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I am really not a big fan of that `android:onClick="newGame"` stuff. You should try it the good old-fashioned way, like this:

```
public class TitleScreen extends Activity {

    private Button newBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_title_screen);

        this.newBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newBtn);
        this.newBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newGameIntent = new Intent(this, createNewGameActivity.class);
                startActivity(newGameIntent);   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
public class TitleScreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button newBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_title_screen);

        this.newBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newBtn);
        this.newBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent newGameIntent = new Intent(this, createNewGameActivity.class);
        startActivity(newGameIntent);
    }
}
```

---

If you are dealing with multiple `Buttons` you can handle them in one `OnClickListener` like this:

```
private final View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final int id = view.getId();
        switch (id) {

            case R.id.newBtn:
                Intent newGameIntent = new Intent(this, createNewGameActivity.class);
                startActivity(newGameIntent);
                break;

            case R.id.otherButton:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Other Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.cancelButton:
                ...
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

You get the id of the calling `View` and use a switch to differentiate between the specific `Buttons`. For example in your `Activity` you can implement this like this:

```
public class TitleScreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button newBtn;
    private Button otherBtn;
    private Button cancelBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_title_screen);

        this.newBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newBtn);
        this.newBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.otherBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.otherBtn);
        this.otherBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.cancelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
        this.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int id = view.getId();
        switch (id) {

            case R.id.newBtn:
                Intent newGameIntent = new Intent(this, createNewGameActivity.class);
                startActivity(newGameIntent);
                break;

            case R.id.otherBtn:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Other Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.cancelBtn:
                ...
                break;
        }        
    }
}
```

---

A few things that caught my eye:

- The names of classes are supposed to start with an upper case letter, so instead of `createNewGameActivity` you `Activity` should be called `CreateNewGameActivity`.
- Use `Fragments`. The golden age of `Activities` is over. Since `Fragments` were introduced `Activities` are just supposed to be containers for the `Fragments`. So even if you just have one `Button` in your layout you should have an empty `Activity` which just contains one `Fragment` and in that `Fragment` you implement your UI and logic.
- Don't use `android:onClick`. There is no indication in the code that this method will be called at all. And there is no reason for the layout to assume that such a method exists anywhere in the `View`, `Fragment` or `Activity` which loads the layout. And aside from that it isn't even that convenient. In 99,9% of all cases in which you need to set an `OnClickListener` you also need to do other stuff with the `Button` and then you need the reference anyway. `android:onClick` just clutters your code and makes it more confusing. it spreads implementation details out and obscures it to the developer. That the layout knows or even defines specific implementation details is in itself already pretty bad.

Comment: OK, you may not like it but I used it extensively in my other app and it was fine. TBH, heck of a lot simpler than the 'old ways' :-)

Comment: Sure it works, it's just not clean in my opinion. There is no indication in the code that this method will be called at all. And there is no reason for the layout to assume that such a method exists in anywhere in the `View`, `Fragment` or `Activity` which loads the layout. It's just bad there is no reason for it to exist at all.

Comment: And what use do you get from it anyway? In 99,9% of all cases in which you need to set an `OnClickListener` you also need to do other stuff with the `Button` and then you need the reference anyway.

Comment: Maybe you are used to it but to me it is horribly clunky and un-intuitive. My other app has screens with 4 buttons on them - the code would look horrendous if I had to do it this way. But thank you for your advice and I will use this method if no-one can explain why the other method isn't working...

Comment: @Nelmo That's just another drawback of `android:onClick`. It should work, nobody knows where the error is, or why nothing happens. It's jut bad and hides important stuff from the developer. And all those click listeners really don't take that much room. But I will edit a way to handle multiple button clicks very quick and simple into my question.